# Unable to hold form 1 value after submitting form 2

Tags: php

I'm trying to submit form 2 while form 1 still holds its input value. The value appears to be held when I print it in but after I submit form 1,but when i submit form 2, it disappears. I have to use php and cannot use anything else.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rego.css">
<title>Registration</title>
<script>

</script>
<?php
 $fname = " ";
 $lname = " ";
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
             $fname = $_POST["fname"];
 }
  if (isset($_POST["submit2"])){
             $fname = $_POST["fname"];
             $lname = $_POST["lname"];
 }


?>
<body>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id = "form1" name = "form1" >
   <table>
            <tr><td><label for="fname">First Name:</label></td><td><input name="fname" type="text" value="<?PHP print $fname; ?>" required></td></tr>
    </table>
<input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" name = "reset" value="Reset">

</form>

<form method="post" id = "form2"  action="http://tl28serv.uws.edu.au/twainfo/form.asp">
<table>
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?=$_POST['fname'];?>">
      <tr><td><label for="lname">Last name:</label></td><td><input name="lname" type="text"   value="<?PHP print $lname; ?>"required></td></tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" name = "submit2" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="reset" name = "reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes because the `form2` doesnt have the value of `form1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your first form submits the field `fname` to your `form2` store it somewhere. One way can be to store it as a hidden field on form 2, then you can easily carry it through.

Add this to your form 2

```
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?php echo $_POST['fname'];?>">
```

Comment: when i submit form 2 know, it says "<?=$_POST['fname'];?>" am i meant to use php tags for that on your code? also do i put it inside the table? Cheers